# zypper can't access repositories in opensuse leap 42.3

Tags: opensuse, repository, zypper

It shows the following error when trying to update or refresh using `zypper`, but I can access these links from Google Chrome.

> Timeout exceeded when accessing 'http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/leap/42.3/repo/non-oss/content'

I've tried disabling the IPV6 in Yast and used

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

and

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

I also added the above lines to the /etc/sysctl.conf file. (I rebooted the system each time.)

Answer (score 2):

The download server was very recently hit with a catastrophic hardware failure, try again in a few hours or tomorrow.

If you ever have doubts you can check https://status.opensuse.org/